# ++ value or value ++ in rails (ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, operators

Does ruby on rails have an equivalent to ++value.

In c there's a ++x and a x++

They are not the same operation (strictly speaking).. 
Does rails have something simular

```
c++ code
int x = 0;
if(x++) cout << "value is not zero when compared"
else    cout << "value still zero when compared"
//prints   "value still zero when compared"

x = 0;
if(++x) cout << "value is not zero when compared"
else   cout << "value is still zero when compared"
//prints "value is not zero when compared"
```

The ++x is a faster operation (small but faster), but that's not why I want it.. I want to print and add a value in the same line.. But I want to print out the value before the addition.

ruby code

```
#print out the count of products processed, the current id, and the current name
p "#{recCount++}:#{product.id} #{product.name}";
```

Comment: It does not look like post-increment is there ([link](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/02/26/ruby-or-why-post-increment-is-tricky/)).

Comment: fab link :).. leaves me sad.. Being a "language lawyer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't, but it has `+= 1`.

Comment: blisteringly slower than inc.. but when is it ratified?  Before it prints, or after?  if the recount is 10 and I call the above with += 1, then what gets printed?  10, or 11?

Comment: @daveatflow Slower than an operator that doesn't exist?

Comment: inc exists.. On every processor built in the last 15 years. We who love the metal still see it.

Comment: @daveatflow Are you telling me `+= 1` doesn't compile to `inc`?

Comment: += is much slower than x++  and slower still than ++x.. But that's not really the point of the question.. I'm just looking to play with the evaluation times on operations.

Comment: not just inc.. I don't believe it does.  it doesn't in c, so I'd expect it wouldn't in rails.

Comment: @daveatflow Rails isn't a language. Not every language has equivalent constructs to C.

Comment: sorry.. I meant ruby :) the point of the question was to ask if it had the same construct.  It was me hoping it would have a post-increment, to make my code a smidge smaller. :)  Sometimes I look back and see code that is so much smaller, so much tighter.  I long for it, and code in ruby like a c++ guy. I can't help it.